# Getting custom properties and version with openXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an OpenXML-Excel document in a specific version with some custom properties. When I look at the xml-structure of that file, these properties are stored under `.\customXml\item2.xml`:

(Part of it)

```
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:Status"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:Duedate" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:SpId" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:TemplateName" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:MailSent" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:Company" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:WeeklyReminderSent" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="ns2:DailyReminderSent" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:all>
```

In addition, this file has also revisions enabled.

Now I need to read these values using OpenXML (Or ClosedXML)

I tried to following to received these data.
ClosedXML:

```
var workBook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook("myfile.xlsx");
var props = workBook.Properties;
var custProps = workBook.CustomProperties;
```

OpenXML:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
  using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
  {
    var coreprops = doc.CoreFilePropertiesPart;
    var custprops = doc.CustomFilePropertiesPart;
    var extprops = doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart;
  }
}
```

Both approaches did not contain any of the stored custom properties in either of the objects (props, custprops, coreprops, extrprops)

How can I collect those Informations the OpenXML-Way?

Comment: ref this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656727/openxml-read-customxmlpart

Answer (score -1):

Using OpenXML sdk 2.5

You get the CustomPropertiesPart but you need to get Properties from that:

```
CustomFilePropertiesPart customPropsPart = doc.CustomFilePropertiesPart;
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties.Properties props = customPropsPart.Properties;

foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties.CustomDocumentProperty prop in props)
{
  //do what you want to do... in my case I have only one Text property...
  String propName = prop.Name;
  String value = prop.VTLPWSTR.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: My properties are **NOT** stored inside the CustomProperties. I only have a custom property with the Name "ContentTypeId" there, which is from "\docProps\custom.xml", but NOT from the path mentioned above

Comment: Have you already tried snooping around each document's part? eg IEnumerable<OpenXmlPart> parts = doc.GetPartsOfType<OpenXmlPart>();